# Incorrect Test cases count for skipped tests in testng

Tags: java, testng

I used the following code to get the count of the skipped Test cases count

```
public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    skippedTests =context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults();

   for (ITestResult temp : skippedTests) {
            ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
            if (context.getSkippedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
                skippedTests.remove(temp);} else {
                if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    skippedTests.remove(temp);
                }
                else{if(context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0){
                skippedTests.remove(temp);
               }
                }
            }
        }
```

But many of the times when suite executes completely the skipped test case count gives count of all skipped methods (i.e including beforeclass skipped , before method skipped..etc) rather than just the count of skipped Test cases.

Please let me know  what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all the **Non Test** methods from your set at the end, as shown below

```
public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    Set<ITestResult> skippedTests = context.getSkippedTests().getAllResults();

    for (ITestResult temp : skippedTests) {
        ITestNGMethod method = temp.getMethod();
        //If the method is not a @Test annotated method, then lets remove that from the skipped lists
        if (!method.isTest()) {
            skippedTests.remove(temp);
            continue;
        }
        if (context.getSkippedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
            skippedTests.remove(temp);
        } else {
            if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                skippedTests.remove(temp);
            } else {
                if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                    skippedTests.remove(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```